# Stop Android File Transfer Popping Up

Tags: file-transfer, nexus-7, macos

Bit annoying that Android File Transfer pops up whenever I connect my Nexus 7 to the Macbook. Is there any way to keep it active but hidden initially?

Comment: Solution [Stop Android File Transfer application auto-starting on OS X](http://monkeyhybrid.com/2013/12/stop-android-file-transfer-application-auto-starting-on-os-x/)  worked for me for mac.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In my case the Android File Transfer App made my whole Macbook touch input freeze, so I had to find a away around this problem. The solution from this page worked: https://cooltrainer.org/taming-android-file-transfer-on-mac-os-x/

1. Kill all Android File Transfer (AFT) processes using Activity Monitor
2. Remove AFT from your login items
3. Remove the agent with the following terminal command:

   ```
   rm -r ~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Android\ File\Transfer/Android\ File\ Transfer\ Agent.app
   ```
4. Rename the agents copy with:

   ```
   cd /Applications/Android\ File\ Transfer.app/Contents/Resources 
   mv Android\ File\ Transfer\ Agent.app Android\ File\ Transfer\Agent.app.disable
   ```

Answer (score 4):

- Go to `System preferences > Users & groups`
- Choose your user
- Select login items

In the list, select `android file transfer agent` and remove it using the button with a `-` on it.

Now, you are free :D

Comment: This only stops it appearing when logging in. (It's off by default anyway.) I want to prevent it when I connect Android devices.

Comment: Did you even tried ? This stop the agent to start. The role of the agent is to open the soft when you plug your phone.

Comment: Have you tried it yourself? It's just that I've read elsewhere the app will re-register itself when you run it. Unfortunately, I've messed something up using another suggestion to rename it, and can't easily try it now.

Comment: Obviously I tried myself. I won't post an answer if I didn't. I work every days on a mac and plus my android phone every day on it as well. I'm testing this every days.

Comment: This did not work for me.

Answer (score -1):

Open Activity Monitor, select a process `Android File Transfer Agent`, click `Quit Process`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks but I want this to happen automatically every time. Also, I think that will kill it altogether rather than leaving it in the background.